# How to use interceptors to handle response globally

Tags: javascript, axios

I have just started exploring axios and using interceptors

In my code, I have axios api call here and there, So I used interceptors to handle error,

but it still show uncaught error in my console. I dont know why is that?

For example, this is my api code:

```
export const getcountryAllocations = async (country: string) => {
  const response = await instance.get<IcountryAllocationTypeResponse[]>(
    `/asa/${country}`
  )
  return response.data
}
```

So, in order to handle error in a centralized way, I used interceptors to handle error.

```
export const instance = axios.create()

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  res => {
    return res
  },
  error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    throw error
  }
)
```

But I still get a red error in console when I get api request error, say the example api I mentioned above

```
GET http://localhost:30087/asa/USD 401 (Unauthorized)

AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

But I expect that it shouldnt display localhost/:1 Uncaught anymore, as I have handled it in interceptors

Comment: What should Axios return if an error occurs?

Comment: Since the way I wrote this error handling is from a template, I dont understand why it wrote throw instead of return. Is it I need to write .catch after each api call no matter what?

Answer (score 1):

You are catching the error but then throwing it again. That's why you still have the red error in the console.

What you can do is catch the error and then return an object saying an error occurred without throwing it again.

```js
export const instance = axios.create()

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  res => {
    return res
  },
  error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      console.log(error)
    }

    return {
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
      status: error.response.status
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. May I ask, when I return res, how will it interact with the .then method?  The reason I ask this is that I think the returned res will return to the .then method. So if I return an object, it will return to .catch method, which I didn't provide in the API call, and in fact, I want to avoid doing so as well

Comment: what if I dont write a return statement? I tested and I dont see a difference?

Comment: The response you return here will be forwarded to the .then method. If you don't return anything in your interceptor, the res in your .then will be undefined but it will work.

Comment: I see, as for the return obj in error callback. Does it mean that .catch callback in api would not be executed anymore, if there is any, because there is a error callback in interceptors already.